# Use JQuery to multiply values from dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, siblings

I'm using JQuery to dynamically create table rows. Each row contains 3 text fields. As users type into a text field, the table row is cloned and multiple rows are added as required.  All that works fine.

Numerical values are entered into the first 2 fields, which are multiplied. The output automatically appears in the 3rd text box. As the input fields are clones, I can't use getElementById to run the function & multiply the values.

I was told to use `onchange` using parent siblings, but I don't know how to do that. Can someone give me an example?

Here is a sample of my code in JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mzctb778/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are adding things dynamically you should use event delegation to listen for change events. Do this by attaching it to the table. So listen for a change on an input. Once you detect the change, get the row by looking up the DOM and select the inputs you need to multiply. Since you can not use ids since they need to be unique, use classes to reference the elements.

```js
$("table").on("change", "input", function () {  //use event delegation
  var tableRow = $(this).closest("tr");  //from input find row
  var one = Number(tableRow.find(".one").val());  //get first textbox
  var two = Number(tableRow.find(".two").val());  //get second textbox
  var total = one * two;  //calculate total
  tableRow.find(".three").val(total);  //set value
});

$("button.add").on("click", function() {
   var tbody = $("table tbody");
   tbody.find("tr:eq(0)").clone().appendTo(tbody).find("input").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="one" /></td>
      <td><input class="two" /></td>
      <td><input class="three" readonly="readonly"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: So what is your problem now trying to adapt what I did to yours? I am not going to do all your work.

Comment: Hi, your code is very useful for me thanks, can you explain how to sum of all class="three". and display

Answer (score -3):

Add this to your script and it will do the calculations you want:

```
$("table select").on("change", function(){
var x=$(this).find(":selected").val();
var y=$(this).closest("td").siblings().find(":selected").val();
$(this).closest("td").siblings().find("input").val(x*y);
});
```

[New JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzctb778/3/)

Comment: Get the values from the first 2 fields and multiply them. Would make it easier to see his code.

Comment: Sure but honestly you shouldn't try to answer a so badly asked question because this is impossible to give relevant answer

Comment: Fair enough. Thought there might have been a possibility that seeing the on function could be enough for him.

Comment: a JS Fiddle has been posted, feel free to revise your answer. (I did not downvote)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer now. It does as was requested.